# Why can't i echo my results from MySQL in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli

I try to show every result that the current username has in the database,
but it won't work..
I've tried anything and ya'll are my last hope.
Thanks in advance!

I can not get any answer from my code here below:

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once('../inc/db/config.php');
$mysqli = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);

if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
    exit();
}

$query = "SELECT serverip, servername FROM servers WHERE username=".$_SESSION['user_name']."";

 $results = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);


 if(mysqli_num_rows($results) >= 1)
{

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results))
{
  echo "<hr/>"; 
  echo "<a href='../s_info.php?server='" . $row['serverip'] . "><h2>" . $row['servername'] . "</h2>";
}
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line looks suspect to me:

```
$query = "SELECT serverip, servername FROM servers WHERE username=".$_SESSION['user_name']."";
```

Try:

```
$query = "SELECT serverip, servername FROM servers WHERE username='{$_SESSION['user_name']}'";
```

You should be able to echo out that string as a test and run it separately in mysql command line/phpMyAdmin or whatever tool allows you to test sql statements.  Insure that it returns a result.

Comment: The first line does not prove problems. Unless in  higher versions of MySQL This throws an exception/notice/warning. That i'm unsure, but on MySQL Engines i've worked in & PHP. Not having the `'` is not necessarily a problem

Comment: @DarylGill Yes it is. It does cause an error, but his code wasn't checking for an error. I'll bet if he checked his PHP error log he'd see a message about a wrong argument type for `mysql_num_rows()`

Comment: @DarylGill Just because someone says they tried everything, it doesn't mean that they tried looking at logs or adding `echo mysqli_error($mysqli)`